# single sign on for wordpress multi site

Tags: multisite, multisite-user-management

I am having two wordpress site with multi site concept. I have configured all settings in wp-config.php and .htaccess files. After all still am unable to login in my network sites by using main site user name and password.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I set up single sign on for multiple WP installs across the same domain?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30138/how-do-i-set-up-single-sign-on-for-multiple-wp-installs-across-the-same-domain)

Comment: @Aravona I have configured all table prefix but am unable to login with same details

Comment: you may want to update your question to be more specific to your problem then as currently it reads differently :)

Comment: @Aravona I have modify my question